# Where is pyvenv script in Python 3 on Windows installed?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

After reading the following statement from PEP [405](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/)

> A pyvenv installed script is also provided to make this more
>   convenient:
>
> `pyvenv /path/to/new/virtual/environment`

I tried to create a new virtual environment and failed miserably;

```
C:\>python --version
Python 3.3.1
C:\>pyvenv myvenv
'pyvenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Apparently `pyvenv` script is not installed into `Scripts` folder which is being usually added to the `PATH` environment variable making it possible to easily run such scripts on the command line.

Is PEP 405 wrong, was it not properly implemented in Python 3.3 or am I missing something?

Answer (score 15):

It looks like `pyvenv` script is placed in `Tools\Scripts` subfolder inside Python installation folder (`sys.prefix`). It seems like copying it to `Scripts` subfolder is a good idea as it allows to simply type `pyvenv` from the command line (assuming `Scripts` folder is already on the `PATH`). As there's no `exe` wrapper for this script one has to make sure

- `.py` extension is added to `PATHEXT` environment variable so that
  Windows finds Python script placed on the `PATH` when typing script's
  name at the command prompt.
- `.py` extension is associated either with Python executable or with Python launcher (`py.exe`) which is available starting from Python 3.3

Alternatively one can just type `python -m venv` instead of `pyvenv` and save himself all of the hassle...

Related Python bug [17480](http://bugs.python.org/issue17480) - *pyvenv should be installed someplace more obvious on Windows*

Comment: In all python3 version its in ../Python/Python##-##/Tools/scripts/pyvenv.py
Adding it to path fixes the problem. Else use the command by giving full path of the script and run.
viz. if you use cygwin to mimic unix in windows use
/cygdrive/c/Users/#####/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Tools/scripts/pyvenv.py
Simple yet powerful command to create virtualEnvironment. If called with full path no need to add to System PATH variable.

Answer (score 3):

Use `python -m venv someenvname` instead.

Moreover, there is no strong reason to add python folder to `PATH` if you use system-wide `python.exe` only for creating virtual environments.

Comment: *Use python -m venv someenvname instead.* – that's what I wrote in my answer which was already one year old when you posted yours...