# Python and Virtualenv on Windows

Tags: python, virtualenv

How do you install virtualenv correctly on windows?

I downloaded virtualenv1.9.1 from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and tried installing it with:

```
python virtualenv.py install
```

but it does not appear in MyPythonPath/Scripts

I tried the same way installing [virutalenvwrapper-win](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win) and it installed correctly. But I can't use it because I don't have virtualenv

> python.exe: can't open file
>   'MyPythonPath\Scripts\virtualenv-script.py': [Errno 2 ] No such file or
>   directory

Comment: For Python v3 you probably want `pyvenv` which can be found from this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981111/where-is-pyvenv-script-in-python-3-on-windows-installed

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The suggested way to install Python packages is to use `pip`

Please follow this documentation to install `pip`: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/

Note: Python 2.7.9 and above, and Python 3.4 and above include pip already.

Then install `virtualenv`:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: You're welcome. A suggestion about filtering learning resources: always go for language official documentations first, then maybe SO and/or Google :)

Comment: I installed stuff with pip and still have the missing virtualenv-script.py error, but I'm attempting to install on powershell which may be complicating things.

Comment: @rschwieb installing it on powershell should be fine. Checkout http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#activate-script for details under Windows environments.

Comment: PermissionError. My python installation is in program files. Workaround?

Answer (score 12):

Since I got the same error as mentioned in the question inspite of installing with:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

I would like to add a few points, that might also help someone else solve the error in a similar way as me. Don't know if that's the best way, but for me nothing else helped.

#### Install virtualenv

pip install virtualenv

#### Move into Scripts directory

```
cd C:\Python27\Scripts
```

#### Create a virtual env.

```
python virtualenv.exe my_env
```

#### Activate the virtual env.

```
my_env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

#### Deactivate the virtual env.

```
my_env\Scripts\deactivate.bat
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to do it from cmd. PowerShell gave me some errors

Answer (score 5):

1. install virtualenv

   > pip install virtualenv
2. create a virtual environment

   > python -m virtualenv demoEnv
3. Activate the environment

   > demoEnv\Scripts\activate
4. To deactivate

   > deactivate

Answer (score 3):

There is an other way to install Python packages.

1: download the package, you want

2: open commander (press the win start-button and search for cmd)

3: cd into the folder where you downloaded your package

4: type:  "python setup.py install"

Answer (score 2):

For installing virtualenv, you'll have to either install it using pip as mentioned in the answer by woozyking or you'll have to do something like this:

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.9.1.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-1.9.1.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-1.9.1
$ [sudo] python setup.py install
```

The command which you have used can be used to create a virtualenv. I would recommend you go through these small videos on virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper to get a better understanding:

[python-power-tools-virtualenv](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-power-tools-virtualenv/)

[virtualenvwrapper](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-power-tools-virtualenvwrapper/)

Answer (score 2):

## Creating a Virtual Environment on Windows

---

### 1. Create a virtual environment

```
python -m venv myenv
```

### 2. Activate

```
.\myenv\Scripts\activate
```

### 3. Extra information

- To disable write

  - `deactivate`
- These commands will also work on windows

  - `myenv\Scripts\activate`
  - `myenv\Scripts\activate.bat`
  - `.\myenv\Scripts\activate.bat`
- Be careful with slashes:

  - <strike>`myenv/Scripts/activate.bat`</strike>
- I prefer using this naming:

  - `python -m venv .venv`
  - `.venv\Scripts\activate`

### 4. Screenshot

[image]

### 5. Sources

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask