# How do you install virtualenv for python on command prompt?

Tags: python, cmd, virtualenv

I have been trying for two days on installing virtualenv on cmd prompt.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: I don't know how to install it on cmd. Do you know?

Comment: `venv` comes with recent versions of Python, ready to be run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python and Virtualenv on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737203/python-and-virtualenv-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using Windows.

To install virtualenv in windows, follow these steps:

1. Open scripts folder where pip is located in cmd
2. Type `pip install virtualenv`
3. Then you should install virtualenv wrapper for windows. Type this code `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`
4. Create project dir: `mkvirtualenv myproject`
5. Set myproject dir as current dir: `setprojectdir ..../myprojectdir`
6. You are good to go. When you want to deactivate, simply type `deactivate`

Comment: FYI: You can set the project directory with the `-p` switch to `mkvirtualenv` too.