# Can't run flask app from git bash on windows

Tags: python, flask, windows-10, git-bash

I'm having trouble running my `Flask` app on `GitBash` for Windows. When I activate my virtualenv and I do:

```
python main.py
```

My Bash becomes frozen for a few seconds, then it displays the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\shrey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
  32\lib\http\server.py", line 137, in server_bind
  socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\shrey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
  32\lib\socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
  self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way 
  forbidden by its access permissions
```

Can anyone help? It's getting really annoying and I'm not able to QA my code at all. Any help is appreciated- thanks!

Comment: Why are you running it in git bash?

Comment: I've tried to run it from bash, but it throws the same error.

Comment: I'll rephrase, you're on windows, why aren't you running it from powershell?

Comment: With powershell, I can't even activate my virtualenv.

Comment: Any other suggestions though?

Comment: Yes. 1. Use Linux subsystem for windows. 2. use linux in a VM 3. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737203/python-and-virtualenv-on-windows).

Comment: How do I install a VM 3?

Comment: No, I meant run linux in a VM, and the 3 is the third thing (linked to another SO answer). To use a linux VM, use virtualbox, vmware, whatever. If it were me, and it had to be windows, I'd run whatever version of linux we use in production (Ubuntu LTS generally) in a virtualbox VM and work on stuff there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized my error. I had run `netstat -ban` and realized that the port I was trying to run it on (port 5000) was banned and therefore was causing all of my problems. In my `main.py` app I changed my code to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(port=1000)
```

And it worked. Finally!