# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython3/bin/pip3' ( kivy app )

Tags: python, xcode, kivy

Since I got this error when building project in Xcode,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

and then I'm trying to install the requests module with git command.

```
python toolchain.py pip install requests
```

However, I read the logs and I got this FileNotFoundError message. How can I deal with the error?

```
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'host_setuptools3'
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'hostopenssl'
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'hostpython3'
[INFO    ] Global: hostpython located at /Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython3/bin/python
[INFO    ] Global: hostpgen located at /Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython3/bin/pgen
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'ios'
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'kivy'
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'libffi'
[INFO    ] Include dir added: {arch.arch}/ffi
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'openssl'
[INFO    ] Include dir added: {arch.arch}/openssl
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'pyobjus'
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'python3'
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'sdl2'
[INFO    ] Include dir added: common/sdl2
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'sdl2_image'
[INFO    ] Include dir added: common/sdl2_image
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'sdl2_mixer'
[INFO    ] Include dir added: common/sdl2_mixer
[INFO    ] Using the bundled version for recipe 'sdl2_ttf'
[INFO    ] Include dir added: common/sdl2_ttf
[INFO    ] Executing pip with: ['install', '--isolated', '--prefix', '/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3', 'requests']
[INFO    ] Running Shell: /Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython3/bin/pip3 ('install', '--isolated', '--prefix', '/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3', 'requests') {'_env': {'CC': '/bin/false', 'CXX': '/bin/false', 'PYTHONPATH': '/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/dist/root/python3/lib/python3.9/site-packages', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2'}, '_iter': True, '_out_bufsize': 1, '_err_to_out': True}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 3, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1555, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1299, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.command)()
  File "/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1514, in pip
    _pip(sys.argv[2:])
  File "/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 1186, in _pip
    shprint(pip_cmd, *args, _env=pip_env)
  File "/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/kivy_ios/toolchain.py", line 55, in shprint
    cmd = command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/posEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 1524, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/posEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 780, in __init__
    self.process = OProc(self, self.log, cmd, stdin, stdout, stderr,
  File "/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/posEnv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 2125, in __init__
    raise ForkException(fork_exc)
sh.ForkException: 

Original exception:
===================

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/gordonkwok/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/<myenv>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 2080, in __init__
        os.execve(cmd[0], cmd, ca["env"])
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/Users/<myname>/Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython3/bin/pip3'
```

So I looked the file "/Users//Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython3/bin/pip3" and the virtual environment file "/Users//Desktop/kivy/kivy-ios//lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py" to see whether they are existed. And both of them are really existed! I'm so confuse with this error. So please help me out here! It is the finally step for me to run my first app soon! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried many ways to solve the issue in the last few days but failed. Finally, an admin in the kivy discord helps me solve the issue.

In my case, maybe I used the command `sudo toolchain.py build python kivy`. However, sudo is bad, and maybe what caused this issue.

After I clean up the build and reinstall all kivy using `toolchain.py build python kivy`, I finally solve the issue. Thank you for the help from the admin and kivy community!

Answer (score 2):

Let's tackle this in steps:

I'm making the assumption that your `toolchain.py` file is the script you would like to run, for which you need the `requests` module.

**Step 1: Activate your virtual environment (you have possibly already done this)**

Before installing a new module using `pip install <module>`, you want to activate your virtual environment, because you want to install it in there.

You can do this by doing:

- In linux: `source <your-venv-path>/bin/activate`
- In windows: `<your-venv-path>\Scripts\activate.bat`

Some good answers on how to activate a virtual environment can be found for [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737203/python-and-virtualenv-on-windows) and for [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604699/how-to-activate-virtualenv-in-linux).

**Step 2: Install the requests module**

Now your virtual environment is active, you should be able to install the requests module like this:

`pip install requests`

**Step 3: Run your script**

After this, you should be able to run your script with the requests module installed like so:

`python toolchain.py`

Comment: I tried but it seems not work for me .